# surface: rows (Z) must be the same as length (Y) and columns (Z) must be the same as length (X) in octave

Tags: octave

I am having a dataset and trying to plot a 3-d plot between the independent and dependent variables.but, I am getting this error whenever I am trying to plot
here is my code:

```
    temp1 = reshape(data(:,1),m,1);
    temp2 = reshape(data(:,2),m,1);
    temp3 = reshape(data(:,3),m,1);
    mesh(temp1,temp2,temp3);
    hold
```

thanks!

Comment: Your question seems to be off-topic here. Also, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Double-check the documentation of `mesh`. `temp3` must be a matrix of size `length(temp1)` x `length(temp2)`, otherwise it won't work. That is literally what the error message is telling you. :)

What are you trying to plot exactly? Maybe you wanted to use `plot3` instead?